# Inheritance java explanation

Tags: java, inheritance

Can someone explain me the execution of this program??
I know what `extends` keyword does. But still I'm unable to figure out what will be the result and why??

```
public class Maryland extends State {
    Maryland() { /* null constructor */ }
    public void printMe() { System.out.println("Read it."); }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Region mid = new State();
        State md = new Maryland();
        Object obj = new Place();
        Place usa = new Region();
        md.printMe();
        mid.printMe();
        ((Place) obj).printMe();
        obj = md;
        ((Maryland) obj).printMe();
        obj = usa;
        ((Place) obj).printMe();
        usa = md;
        ((Place) usa).printMe();
        }
    }

class State extends Region {
    State() { /* null constructor */ }
    public void printMe() { System.out.println("Ship it."); }
    }

    class Region extends Place {
    Region() { /* null constructor */ }
    public void printMe() { System.out.println("Box it."); }
    }

    class Place extends Object {
    Place() { /* null constructor */ }
    public void printMe() { System.out.println("Buy it."); }
}
```

Comment: search and you shall find: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: very long and not readable code snippet, no visible efforts to to understand the problem...

Comment: Every Java program must start at `main()`. What does the first line of this code do? What about the next one? Follow this pattern to figure out what the whole program does. If there is a specific line that you have difficulty understanding, feel free to come back and ask about it specifically.

Comment: @Code-Guru: The program starts with `main()`. It uses multiple classes in the same program where the `main()` function is in `Maryland()` class.

Comment: @xan You do realize I'm not the OP, right? My comment was a hint to the OP as to how to figure it out on his/her own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run it and you'll see the result. What else you need?

```
Read it.
Ship it.
Buy it.
Read it.
Box it.
Read it.
```

Comment: Also, you can add traces (even a naive `System.out.println(someMessage)` to know what's going on in the code. Or use a debugger to see how the code is moving.

Answer (score 2):

Well Remember this rule..........

The **Most Specific version** of the `method` for that `class` will be called, when `Method OverRidding` is used along with `inheritance`.

**Eg:**

`Maryland` class has `printMe()` method which prints **"Read it."**

`State` class has `printMe()` method which prints **"Ship it."**

Now its an example of `Method Overridding` along with `inheritance`, and `Class Polymorphism.`

```
State md = new Maryland();
```

`State` is the **Super class** of `Maryland` class, so its like this..

```
Object Reference Variable of Super class  md  =  Object of Subclass ;
```

And its a typical behavior of Compiler ,that only when the method is present in the Object Reference Variable Class then only its called, cause until and unless the method is present in the Super Class, it won't know anything about it even if its in its sub-class....

So when we do this....

`md.printMe();`

then according to the rule that "Most Specific version of the method for that class will be called", `printMe()` method of Maryland class will be called, so it prints **Read it.**

Comment: Okay. And what about these statements?
`obj = md;

((Maryland) obj).printMe();`

Comment: @user188995 a class always will always implicitly extend the Object class... You are doing an explicit casting of Maryland object, so the again the rule follows and printMe() method of Maryland class is called.

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra : you mean method overriding.  overloading is when you have the same method name with a different set of arguments.

Comment: @Matt yup....i mean method overridding where the Method's arguments are of same number, with same name with same return type, but yes the access modifier can be more widen moving from super class to sub class... and yes thanks matt , it was a typo..i improved it...thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Knowledge about dynamic polymorphism and inheritance is needed. No complexity in the program.
Execute the program in debug mode and check the execution line by line. You will understand the flow.